# Mock value of Enum with python

Tags: python, testing, mocking

i want to change the value of HANDLES_CSV

```
class FileName(str, Enum):
    HANDLES_CSV = "handles.csv"
    HANDLES_JSON = "handles.json"

def test_function():
    FileName.HANDLES_CSV.value = mock.Mock() 
    FileName.HANDLES_CSV.value.return_value = "test.json"
    print(FileName.HANDLES_CSV)
```

i had this error :
AttributeError: can't set attribute

can you help ?

Answer (score -1):

It has nothing to do with mocking, Enums are supposed to work as a constant, not as a variable, so you are not supposed to reassign their values.

Not using the Enum class will allow you to put a mock object there after the definition.

```
class FileName(str):
    HANDLES_CSV = "handles.csv"
    HANDLES_JSON = "handles.json"

FileName.HANDLES_CSV = mock.Mock()
FileName.HANDLES_JSON = "test.json"
```

Anyway, the uppercase names are usually reserved to constant values, so this still seems to be a bit odd.

Comment: i am not tring to reassign their values. just for testing i prefer use another file that why i chosed to mock it

Comment: For testing or not, you are reassigning them. and you literally said "i want to change the value of HANDLES_CSV".